# Create OSX app to run terminal based server

Tags: objective-c, node.js, cocoa, terminal

So I have a server created using node.js, to run the server you have to navigate to the same directory as the "server.js" file and in terminal run the command `node server.js` this starts the server just fine and control+c closes it.

Now my question is, how can I tuck all this behind an OSX Cocoa Mac app (objective-c). Ideally if this was to be made into distributable software, I wouldn't expect users to open up terminal and run commands. So im thinking a start button to somehow discreetly run that command and start the server and a stop button to close the server. Ive looked around the web a bit and cant seem to find a solution.

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't use `fork()` and `exec()` to start it, and `kill()` to stop it. Just make an app with two buttons that do those things. `NSTask` may be an option too.

Comment: Fairly new to all this, will look into that and report back

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty easy with [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit). You can create your interface with html/css/javascript and simply `require` or use other methods to start your server.

Comment: Thank you, looked into it, it seems promising however running the app requires having node-webkit installed ... Its not the native, download from the Mac app store app im after

Comment: You can bundle node-webkit with it and distribute a single .app file. Check out [grunt-node-webkit-builder](https://github.com/mllrsohn/grunt-node-webkit-builder) which will build the distributable for you. Not sure about the app store though.